# Django Exclude in list_filter with custom filter

Tags: python, django, filter, django-admin, filtering

Im trying to do 2 filters so that they appear in the django admin filter sidebar,
the first one is the following 
https://gist.github.com/739760c7de861f76657f
in this one I would like to do filter if Gold exclude that which starts with J and Silver is already working exclude all that does not start with J

The second filter is a bit more complicated, I have a field in my DB that contains a weigth of several people, I would like to be able to filter by ranks of weigth... for example weigths between 50 and 70 and so on...

How would I do this... Thank you so much as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done...

```
class GoldorSilverFilter(DateFieldFilterSpec):
    def __init__(self, f, request, params, model, model_admin):
        super(GoldorSilverFilter, self).__init__(f, request, params, model, model_admin)

        self.links = (
            (_('All'), {}),
            (_('Gold'), {'%s__regex' % self.field.name: '^[^J]',}),
            (_('Silver'), {'%s__istartswith' % self.field.name: 'J',}),
        )

    def title(self):
        return _("Metal")
        #return self.field.name

FilterSpec.filter_specs.insert(0, (lambda f: getattr(f, 'goldorsilverfilter', False), GoldorSilverFilter))
```

I know the return should not be tied to one value but did not know what to do with it... 
about the second poing well I used the same class but used %s_*gte and %s*_lte

Hope this helps someone out..